# How to Test a Concern in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Given that I have a `Personable` concern in my Rails 4 application which has a `full_name` method, how would I go about testing this using RSpec?

**concerns/personable.rb**

```
module Personable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: What testing framework are you using? Also remember Personable is just a normal Ruby module. Test it just like you would test any other mixin.

Comment: Hasn't `ActiveSupport::Concern` been taken out of Rails? I thought it went a little while ago.

Comment: @LeeJarvis I'm using Rspec along w/ FactoryGirl

Comment: Ah, google informs me it was only the `InstanceMethods` module inside `Concern` that was removed. I still think concerns are bad design though. What's wrong with service objects?

Comment: @KyleDecot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542945/testing-modules-in-rspec http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453266/rails-rspec-testing-concerns-class-methods http://benediktdeicke.com/2013/01/custom-rspec-example-groups/ these should help

Comment: @Russell Rails 4 actively promotes concerns (I also agree service objects are a better idea) but unfortunately that's not how Rails core sees it. People just need to remember they're just normal Ruby modules and should be used appropriately.

Comment: @LeeJarvis By "Rails core" I assume you mean "DHH". It's definitely not a good idea to do something just because "Rails core" says to do it that way.

Comment: @Russell I agree. That said, I wouldn't not help someone with their questions just because they were following a Rails-y way of doing something that I didn't agree with it. Anyway this is kinda of escaping the subject of this question :-)

Comment: :-) Agree. Sorry Kyle!

Comment: Not a problem. Always good to get other developers opinions on the subject I'm currently dealing w/

Answer (score 220, accepted):

The method you found will certainly work to test a little bit of functionality but seems pretty fragile—your dummy class (actually just a `Struct` in your solution) may or may not behave like a real class that `include`s your concern. Additionally if you're trying to test model concerns, you won't be able to do things like test the validity of objects or invoke ActiveRecord callbacks unless you set up the database accordingly (because your dummy class won't have a database table backing it). Moreover, you'll want to not only test the concern but also test the concern's behavior inside your model specs.

So why not kill two birds with one stone? By using RSpec's [shared example groups](https://rspec.info/features/3-12/rspec-core/example-groups/shared-examples/), you can test your concerns against the actual classes that use them (e.g., models) *and* you'll be able to test them everywhere they're used. And you only have to write the tests once and then just include them in any model spec that uses your concern. In your case, this might look something like this:

```
# app/models/concerns/personable.rb
module Personable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end

# spec/concerns/personable_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.shared_examples_for "personable" do
  let(:model) { described_class } # the class that includes the concern

  it "has a full name" do
    person = FactoryBot.build(model.to_s.underscore.to_sym, first_name: "Stewart", last_name: "Home")
    expect(person.full_name).to eq("Stewart Home")
  end
end

# spec/models/master_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require Rails.root.join "spec/concerns/personable_spec.rb"

describe Master do
  it_behaves_like "personable"
end

# spec/models/apprentice_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Apprentice do
  it_behaves_like "personable"
end
```

The advantages of this approach become even more obvious when you start doing things in your concern like invoking AR callbacks, where anything less than an AR object just won't do.

Comment: One disadvantage of this is that it will slow down `parallel_tests`. I think it will be better to have separate tests instead of using `shared_examples_for` and `it_behaves_like`.

Comment: @ArtemKalinchuk I'm not sure that's true, per https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/issues/168 `parallel_tests` are based per file, so shared examples should not slow it down. I would also argue that properly grouped shared behaviors, trumps testing speed.

Comment: Make sure to include the `concerns` directory in your `spec_helper.rb` https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/407#issuecomment-1409871

Comment: I couldn't find anything about including the concerns directory in that link.  Could you please clarify how this is done?  I can't get my RSpec test to recognize the module in one of my concerns.

Comment: @JakeSmith see https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples

Comment: The only thing that caught me out here was that I needed to instantiate my model, rather than just using the class. `let(:model) { described_class }` needed to be `let(:model) { described_class.new }` to avoid a nasty ```NoMethodError: undefined method `reflect_on_association' for Class:Class```.

Comment: Do not add `_spec` to the filename which contains shared_examples_for (personable_spec.rb in this case), otherwise you will get a misleading warning message - https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/828.

Comment: it's very very helpfull for me!

Comment: You could probably .build your instance instead of .create and turbocharge your tests.

Comment: `require "concerns/personable_spec"` is enough. The spec folder is in the load path.

Answer (score 77):

In response to the comments I've received, here's what I've ended up doing *(if anyone has improvements please feel free to post them)*:

**spec/concerns/personable_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Personable do
  let(:test_class) { Struct.new(:first_name, :last_name) { include Personable } }
  let(:personable) { test_class.new("Stewart", "Home") }

  it "has a full_name" do
    expect(personable.full_name).to eq("#{personable.first_name} #{personable.last_name}")
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, this will break other tests if they happen to test a real class called `Person`. I'll edit to fix.

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives me the error: `undefined method 'full_name' for #<struct first_name="Stewart", last_name="Home">`

Comment: Try including Personable rather than extending it. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Works great now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and helping me refactor @Russell

Comment: Works great and looks nice

Answer (score 8):

Another thought is to use the [with_model gem](https://github.com/Casecommons/with_model) to test things like this. I was looking to test a concern myself and had seen the [pg_search gem doing this](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/blob/master/spec/lib/pg_search/multisearch_spec.rb). It seems a lot better than testing on individual models, since those might change, and it's nice to define the things you're going to need in your spec.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me. In my case my concern was calling generated **_path* methods and the others approaches didn't seem to work. This approach will give you access to some of the methods only available in the context of a controller.

**Concern:**

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def foo
    ...
  end
end
```

**Spec:**

```
require 'rails_helper'

class MyConcernFakeController < ApplicationController
  include MyConcernFakeController
end

RSpec.describe MyConcernFakeController, type: :controller do    
  context 'foo' do
    it '' do
      expect(subject.foo).to eq(...)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: if the concern is defined in `controllers/concerns/my_concern.rb`, where is your concern spec? 
`spec/controllers/concerns/my_concern_spec.rb`, or `spec/controllers/my_concern_fake_controller_spec.rb`?

Comment: I think that's a matter of preference, but in my case I wanted to test the concern, not the controller (but yes, they're connected) so your first suggestion: `spec/controllers/concerns/my_concern_spec.rb`

Answer (score -3):

just include your concern in spec and test it if it returns the right value.

```
RSpec.describe Personable do
  include Personable

  context 'test' do
    let!(:person) { create(:person) }

    it 'should match' do
       expect(person.full_name).to eql 'David King'
    end
  end
end
```