# guard can't find updated examples when using shared_exapmles_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

To tidy up codes, I separated `RSpec` tests for `concerns` methods to `spec/concerns` directory.

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525222/how-to-test-a-concern-in-rails/20010923#20010923). (Copy & Paste from the answer)

```
# app/models/concerns/personable.rb

module Personable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end

# spec/concerns/personable_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

shared_examples_for "personable" do
  let(:model) { described_class } # the class that includes the concern

  it "has a full name" do
    person = FactoryGirl.create(model.to_s.underscore.to_sym, first_name: "Stewart", last_name: "Home")
    expect(person.full_name).to eq("Stewart Home")
  end
end

# spec/models/master_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

describe Master do
  it_behaves_like "personable"
end

# spec/models/apprentice_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

describe Apprentice do
  it_behaves_like "personable"
end
```

When I edit `personable_spec.rb` guard detect the update, but because there is no example in the file it ends up `No examples found`.

I have to run all spec to test the `personable_spec.rb`. Is there a way to test examples automatically that are defined in `shared_examples_for` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you have to do:

**1-** Do not name your shared example files with the suffix `_spec`, they are not spec file they are support file. I also suggest to group them into a sub-folder named `support` for better file organization.

So move your file `spec/concerns/personable_spec.rb` to `spec/support/concerns/personable.rb`, or even `spec/support/shared_examples/concerns/personable.rb`, or what ever you find suitable.

**2-** Remove the line `require 'spec_helper'` from the suport files, this `require` statement is only required in spec files, not in support files

**3-** Tell rspec to load all files under your `support` by adding at the end of `spec_helper.rb` file:

```
# Load custom matchers and macros, etc
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

**4-** Restart guard and run your test.

**5-** You also need to tell guard to look for change in all files located under the `support` folder and sub-folders, so you won't have to restart guard for every change