# How to test validations in a Model Concern in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a Model Concern to do validations:

```
module UserValidations
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i

  included do
  validates :email,
            :presence   => true,
            :format     => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX,
            :uniqueness => { case_sensitive: false }
  end
end
```

This concern is used for multiple forms.

Now I plan to write spec for this concern so I do not need to test the same set of validations in different form specs. However, I have not found a good way to do it...

I have tried things like this but failed...

```
require 'spec_helper'

class DummyClass
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveRecord::Validations
  include UserValidations

  attributes :email, :first_name, :last_name
end

describe "UserValidations" do
  subject { DummyClass.new }

  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of :email }
end
```

Error stack:

```
/home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/term-ansicolor-1.3.2/lib/term/ansicolor.rb:239:in `term_ansicolor_attributes': wrong number of arguments (3 for 0) (ArgumentError)
  from /home/eyang/grasshopper_dev/gh_user_service/spec/models/concerns/user_validations_spec.rb:8:in `<class:DummyClass>'
  from /home/eyang/grasshopper_dev/gh_user_service/spec/models/concerns/user_validations_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `block in load_spec_files'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `load_spec_files'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  from /home/eyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: How did you end up testing the validations?

Comment: I tested them in models which were using the concern.

Comment: Okay, no worries.  It's unfortunate we weren't able to help you do what you originally wanted.

Comment: No problems. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to include the concern in a dummy class. This question isn't exactly the same but it demonstrates the approach:

[Rails & RSpec - Testing Concerns class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453266/rails-rspec-testing-concerns-class-methods)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how well the following tests would work within the context of a Rails app, but the following is my attempt at testing just your `UserValidations` concern as generically as possible.  You should be able to just copy and paste the code into a file and run rspec on it to test it, and then you can integrate it into your project if it works for you:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'active_model'
require 'active_support'
require 'shoulda-matchers'

module UserValidations
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i

  included do
    validates :email,
              :presence   => true,
              :format     => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX,
              :uniqueness => { case_sensitive: false }
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'sqlite3', database: ':memory:'
)

# Create an 'anonymous' table that has an email field
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :'' do |t|
    t.string :email
  end
end

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :active_record
    with.library :active_model
  end
end

RSpec.describe UserValidations, type: :model do
  let(:user_validate_able) do
    # Instantiate an anonymous class that inherits from AR::Base
    Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
      include UserValidations

      # ActiveModel needs a model name for error messages,
      # so give one to this anonymous class
      def self.model_name
        ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, 'AnonymousModel')
      end
    end.new
  end

  it 'validates presence, uniqueness, and format of email' do
    expect(user_validate_able).to validate_presence_of(:email)
    expect(user_validate_able).to validate_uniqueness_of(:email).case_insensitive
    expect(user_validate_able).to allow_value('guy@incognito.com').for(:email)
  end
end
```